# recursive filling treeview using c#

Tags: c#, recursion, treeview

I have an object of type list from which I wish to use to populate a treeview in c#.
I created a MyObject class for my object

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id;
    public int ParentId;
    public string Name;
}
```

Here is a method to recursivley add tree view nodes based on the list.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
        list.Add(new MyObject(){Id=1, Name="Alice", ParentId=0});
        list.Add(new MyObject(){Id=2, Name="Bob", ParentId=1});
        list.Add(new MyObject(){Id=3, Name="Charlie", ParentId=1});
        list.Add(new MyObject(){Id=4, Name="David", ParentId=2});            

        BindTree(list, null);            
    }
}

private void BindTree(IEnumerable<MyObject> list, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    var nodes = list.Where(x => parentNode == null ? x.ParentId == 0 : x.ParentId == int.Parse(parentNode.Value));
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(node.Name, node.Id.ToString());
        if (parentNode == null)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        }
        else
        {
            parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
        }
        BindTree(list, newNode);
    }
}
```

But the method is failed if I comment this row:

```
list.Add(new MyObject(){Id=1, Name="Alice", ParentId=0});
```

Does any one have a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

That method would fail because after commenting:

```
list.Add(new MyObject(){Id=1, Name="Alice", ParentId=0});
```

because you would then have no objects in the list with a `ParentId` of 0. The problem with that is that you are first calling `BindTree` with a null `TreeNode`:

```
BindTree(list, null);
```

That means that your first line of code within `BindTree` will set `nodes` to an empty enumerable:

```
var nodes = list.Where(x => parentNode == null ? x.ParentId == 0 : x.ParentId == int.Parse(parentNode.Value));
// 'parentNode' is null, so it looks for items in 'list' that have a 'ParentId' of '0'
```

In this case, no items have a `ParentId` of 0...

Comment: i would like to know how to display only child nodes using this recursive method

Comment: Change the '0' to a '1' in the first line of 'BindTree'